# Javascript 'alert' function inside catch block only works when dev tools are opened in chrome

Tags: javascript, popup, google-chrome-devtools, window.open, popup-blocker

Hello StackOverflow community!

I've encountered a very weird problem and couldn't find any useful information on how to solve it.

*Somehow, a piece of javascript code works only when the dev tools window is opened (docked or as a separate window) in google chrome.*

*The original problem*: Due to our application structure, we need to open multiple popups automatically when a page is served. Since the popups are **NOT** opened through a direct user interaction (like onclick), modern browsers would automatically block these popups. Because of the large amount of code that would need to be refactored to avoid this, our *solution* was:

- check if the browser is blocking some popups.
- if so: inform the user about this and suggest to turn off their browser's popup blocking function for 
  our website (by adding it to the exception list for example).

Not a very elegant solution I know, but there was no other way so please don't comment on how to do this differently.

The javascript code:

```
let popupBlockingErrorShown = false;

this.OpenWindow = function (url, name, args) {

        var i = Popups.length; //Popups is an array defined as a global variable that keeps track of all 
                               //opened popup windows

        Popups[i] = window.open(url, name, args);

        try {

            Popups[i].focus();

        } catch (e) {

            if (!popupBlockingErrorShown) {

                alert("very user friendly message explaining to turn of popup blocking");

                popupBlockingErrorShown = true;
            }


        };
    }
```

The windows have to be popups. The *popupBlockingErrorShown* variable is to prevent having an `alert` message for each popup.

Works fine in firefox. But in *google chrome* there is this behaviour:

- **without dev tools open**: the first popup opens normally, the others are blocked, there is **no alert message**.
- **with dev tools open**: the first popup opens but gets 'stuck' on loading (it's an empty page). **The alert message shows normally.**

Keeping the browser-window open and simply switching between dev tools opened or closed gives the same behaviour.

Anyone can help me? Much appreciated!

This is my first stackoverflow question and I'm still very new to programming, I have a bit over a year of experience. Remarks on my 'asking questions'-skills are welcome.

Comment: Modern Chrome doesn't show alert/prompt/confirm in inactive tabs/windows, this is intentional.

Comment: Opening lots of new windows is a pretty bad idea. Disabling the blocking of new windows may not even be possible on some browsers.

Comment: @wOxxOm But how do you explain that the alert does show when you just have dev tools open? I've tried to close the 'previous' popup window `Popups[i-1]` when entering the catch block, which makes the alert work, but this is rather hacky and might close a window that has been opened from a different action and kept open for different purposes by the user.

Comment: devtools sets "user present" flag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to wOxxOm's comment I've found a workaround. So the problem was related to what window was focused on. I've added a piece of code in the `catch-block` to show an alert on a successfully opened popup (if there is one) :

```
   try {

           Popups[i].focus();

        } catch (e) {

            if (!popupBlockingErrorShown) {
                if (Popups[i - 1]) { //there is a previous popup and it's been focused on.
                    Popups[i - 1].alert(UIMessages[33]); //show alert on opened popup.
                    popupBlockingErrorShown = true;
                }
                else {
                    alert(UIMessages[33]);
                    popupBlockingErrorShown = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks @wOxxOm !